# Cron won't start

Tags: cron

I have a smaller Drupal 7 Aquia site and Cron will run successfully if I press the button manually. The issue is that it just won't ever start on its own. The scheduler doesn't seem to be working.

- Cron can finish successfully
- I tried the Elysia Cron module but it doesn't make a difference.
- I've tried visiting the website myself, nothing.
- Visiting the cron page mywebsite.com/cron.php?cron_key=KEYHERE does make cron run, so that's good and well
- I made sure the cron keys match

In my webhosting panel, I have a Cron Job task set up, it looks like :

```
 /usr/bin/wget -O - -q "http://mywebsite.com/cron.php?cron_key=CRONKEY" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

What's going wrong and how can I fix the problem where cron just isn't automatically triggered?

Comment: Does poorman's cron work on your site?  Does the `wget` cron job set up in the webhosting panel actually run correctly (don't redirect its output to `/dev/null`, but to a file where you can examine it)?

Comment: did you try from backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that my Cron panel had a place for email notifications and like @Free Radical said, some output was critical to debugging.

Basically, some website hosters - like GoDaddy - have inexplicably finicky cron processes.  The GoDaddy suggested (hah!) cron task of

```
 /usr/bin/wget -O - -q "http://mywebsite.com/cron.php?cron_key=CRONKEY" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

was never ever going to work. As with many things webhost, we don't know why, just that it's a no-go. So I went digging on the Drupal forums and found one that was compatible. This works :

```
 curl http://mywebsite.com/cron.php?cron_key=CRONKEY
```

So the answer is to give the webhost the finger and use the `curl` unix command, instead.